# How can I remove expanding foam residue?

Tags: cleaning, spray-foam

After closing a gap in my kitchen using expansion foam I got residue left on my cupboard.

I have tried rinsing it off with water and mineral turpentine but no luck!

I'm hesitant scraping it off with a blade since it will damage with cupboard.

What substance / chemical can get rid of it?

Product in question:

https://www.bunnings.com.au/sika-850ml-sika-boom-expanding-foam_p1210302

Comment: Check the can for cleanup instructions.  In order for anyone here to maybe be of assistance we should know what kind of surface it's stuck on? Tile? Granite? Formica? Something else?

Comment: @jsotola provide an answer or some advice, the OP did try mechanical method is all that is referenced  once cured on there web site. I did not see cured cleanup different than the OP tried. I would not use Brake cleaner unless testing it in a totally hidden spot. Brake cleaner can dissolve paint, varnish lane even dissolve some plastic.

Comment: if you still have the can of the foam, make a test chunk of the foam. ... then try everything that you have in your garage, like paint thinners, etc. then try everything in your house, like alcohol, nailpolish remover, vinegar, etc. ... if you find something that dissolves the test foam, then use it on a hidden part of the cabinet

Comment: Are the cabinets painted

Answer (score 1):

Use chlorinated brake cleaner typically sold in an auto parts store.

Comment: Any experience or resources you can share to support your suggestion? Cured urethane is notoriously difficult to clean up without a dedicated product. Have you used this one for this purpose?

Comment: Works instantly dissolves the foam, but it might not be great for the finish underneath.